# Regex pattern to get answers between two questions

Tags: python, regex

How do I get the text between the end of the question (starting after ?) and the text before the next question that starts with "Question"?

They answers are separated by new lines

```
import re
text = "Which feature is not part of the linux system?
pipe
2) dirx
ls
ps

Question 2 ("

output= re.findall(r'\?\s*(.*?)\s*Question\)', splitext).split('\n')
print(output)
```

Comment: What output do you want given the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a capture group, matching lines in between that do not end on a question mark and do not start with `Question`

```
^.*\?((?:\n(?!.*\?$|Question\b).*)+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\?` Match a line ending on `?`
- `(` capture **group 1** *(which will be returned by re.findall)*

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

    - `\n(?!.*\?$|Question\b)` Match a newline, and assert that the line does not ends with `?` or starts with Question
    - `.*` If the assertions are true, match the whole line
  - `)*`  Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sTBmbF/1)

For example

```
import re

text = ("Which feature is not part of the linux system?\n"
        "pipe\n"
        "2) dirx\n"
        "ls\n"
        "ps\n\n"
        "Question 2 (")

output = re.findall(r'^.*\?((?:\n(?!.*\?$|Question\b).*)*)', text)
print(output)
```

Output

```
['\npipe\n2) dirx\nls\nps\n']
```

Comment: This one seems to be more versatile I think, I have been using the other answer before but I found it doesn't work for some scenarios for some reason. Thanks both! Is it possible to add another group and get the question too within the same regex call? The question between the "| BD) Listen | >" and 1) ext4 here https://regex101.com/r/wbuvhq/1?

edit: going to do some testing now but I am pretty sure you already did this I see the two groups wow thanks!!

Comment: What if there was no question mark but the answers were still numbers 1) 2) like this example? https://regex101.com/r/vFTkmH/1

Comment: @JohnAnthony Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/06Wusv/1

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex to match required text between `?` and `Question`:

```sh
(?s)(?<=\?).+?(?=\nQuestion )
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3rPSB1/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)`: Enable DOTALL mode to make sure `.` matched line break also
- `(?<=\?)`: Lookbehind to assert that we have `?` just before the current position
- `.+?`: Match 1+ of any characters including line breaks
- `(?=\nQuestion )`: Lookahead to assert that we have a line break followed by `Question`  ahead of the current position